# Tokens All-or-Nothing Atomic Transaction Support

Tags: solidity, transactions, tokens

I'm running into a situation where i need to do an atomic transaction the spans multiple contracts. The issue is it seems that ethereum doesn't support this natively. What i ended up doing is something similar to [QueueBot](https://github.com/SafeMarket/QueueBot) where you have a transaction contract that then takes an aggregate of your call data, splits it and then runs it in one transaction.

Although this works, i had to change my contracts to now use `tx.origin` because the calls are being done by a contract and not the original sender, which i'm not happy with.

Other than the potential security flaws with this approach, this is really ugly too and can be error prone.

Is there any improvements that can be made to this, even if it is just using `msg.sender`, i tried to use delegatecall but i kept getting OOG error, which tells me that's not what it was designed for

Comment: Actually, i already ran into an issue now where i'm running a [Token](https://www.ethereum.org/token) contract, i'm trying to run transfers from 2 separate accounts at the same time, but now it's using the sender of the wrapping transaction instead of the ones from the calldata, this is a problem. How can ethereum not have this feature. Shocking actually

Comment: Welcome!  Would you mind editing your question and title with the details of what you were trying to do with tokens per your comment?  It would be clearer for readers and @Edmund has provided a very good answer.

Answer (score 3):

So to be clear, the issue is that although Ethereum supports atomic transactions - this is the default model for the way contracts work - it does it in the form of wrapping the various individual calls in a single contract call, which as you say sets `msg.sender` to the address of the wrapper contract. But the normal way of making tokens involves looking at `msg.sender` to see who you are sending funds from.

The normal pattern for handling this with tokens is to first make a call from the owner of the funds to the token contract telling it to `approve()` transfers made by the wrapper contract. Instead of calling `transfer()`, the wrapper contract can then call `transferFrom()` to transfer funds up to the maximum approved in the `approve()` call. Since `transferFrom()` has a parameter for the sender, the wrapper contract can specify it rather than leaving the token contract to rely on `msg.sender`.

Comment: Do you have some solidity code to share? I'd like to give this solution a go

Comment: @martintreurnicht check out this implementation of a token contract on Zeppelin: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/StandardToken.sol, specifically the `transferFrom` and `approve` functiosn. It uses exactly this pattern.